# Is it possible to do a PHP PDO Transaction/Commit using 3 (different) databases?

Tags: php, pdo

In an Order application I'm working on, an Order will be stored temporary in a SQLite db-table.
When the Order payment is fully received, in a 'process.php' script I get the Order data from the SQLite db-table.
Next I want to start a PDO transaction and then calling functions (PDO-queries) in an included 'functions.php' to:

1. Saving Order data in MySQL sales.order-table.
2. Saving Payment data in MySQL sales.payment-table.
3. Update 'promotion'-data in MySQL promotion.x-tables.
4. Delete the temporary Order data from SQLite db-table.

Can this be done in one Transaction / Commit?

I have searched for information and examples for my question, but could not find it.

Comment: A "database" is a self-contained set of data tables. You can only do one transaction/commit _within_ such a database. That means if you have 2, or as your title says 3, databases you need 2, or 3, transactions/commits. It's a bit more complicated than this, but the general principle holds.

Comment: I think you can as long as all the databases are in the same server. So if 1, 2, and 3 are in the same server instance, you should be able to. 4 would not since SQLite and MySQL are different servers.

Comment: A better method would be to store the order in the MySQL database directly, and simply add the payment when it is received.

Comment: @KIKO Software, we only consider an 'order' as an Order when it is been paid. Only then we save it in the MySQL database. According to your first answer: to be sure it would work correctly I think I need nested Transactions/Commits. Is that possible?

Comment: Can your `process.php` script signal back to the payment processor whether the payment was processed or not? For instance through an [HTTP response status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)? That would be very useful, in case something fails. Sure you can nest transactions, for different database, but I doubt it is helpful here, what to do if your outer transaction fails after the inner transactions has been committed? The sooner you realize you've made things unnecessarily complicated for yourself, the better.

Comment: @KIKO Software, let me explain some more. We use the Paypal PHP SDK. This has a script Captureorder.php to capture a payment. When the payment is completed (successful) then process.php is called to do the database transactions. So far I don't think that wouln't be too complicated. If it would be true what aynber said in his comment then I can do steps 1, 2 and 3 in one Transaction / Commit; correct?

Comment: Yes, as long as those MySQL databases are part of the same database server, you can use one transaction. Secretly MySQL is one big database, even if you define multiple databases. A database is just an easy way to organize data tables in MySQL.